# Docker redirect to another container with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, docker, docker-compose, apache2

In my app, I have 3 dockers:

- an entry point which is an httpd container
- first api
- second api

I need to redirect all request on the entry point with this pattern: `/api1/...` to the first api and `/api2/...` to the second api.

To do that I try to put this `.htaccess` on the entry point but it doesn't work have you got an idea ? Maybe I don't use the goods things.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/api1/(.*)$ api1_container/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/api2/(.*)$ api2_container/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I still got `404 not found` on `localhost:8080/api1` and `localhost:8080/api2`

Thanks for your help.
Alexis

Comment: You willl first have to make sure that your "apps" can be accessed using a direct request: `https://example.com/api1_container/...` Next: what URL is shown in the requesting browser after the redirection has been done?

Comment: It's really hard to find the cause according to your current description, you'd better give workable image on dockerhub so everyone could reproduce your environment.